# how to check the array element is empty in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

how to check array element is empty. its giving false. how to get the element is blank or not.
in array element contains some space.

Code

```
let TestNumber= DATA-   -    -'
let arrStr =this.TestNumber.split(/[-]/);
if(arrStr[1]==''){
}
```

> output -false

> expected op - true;

```
 data - ['DATA', '   ', '    ', '']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the whitespace for each element.

```js
let arrStr = TestNumber.split(/[-]/).map(x => x.trim());
```

```js
let TestNumber= 'DATA-   -    -';
let arrStr = TestNumber.split(/[-]/).map(x => x.trim());
console.log(arrStr[1] == "");
```

Comment: `console.log(arrStr[1].trim() === "");` would be enough i guess